# How to get first part of a delimited string in batch?

Tags: batch-file, delimiter

I have a string stored in variable %var% which looks like:

`something.contains.text` - a basic string delimited by "."

I need to end up with just "Something" in a new variable.

So far I can only seem to get `contains.text` or just `contains`, but cannot get `something`

Answer (score 4):

While I would solve it with the code in [npocmaka's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27443554/3705191), here's a one-liner for basic strings:

```
set var=something.contains.text
set new_var=%var:.=&rem %
```

The way it works is that it replaces the dots with a command concatenation character (`&`) and starts a comment (`rem`)

Answer (score 1):

```
for /f "tokens=1 delims=." %%a in ("%var%") do set "new_var=%%a"
```

Comment: @PnP: works fine. For use on command prompt (outside a batchfile) replace every `%%a` with `%a`